# Node wont update, despite downloading and installing latest versions

Tags: node.js, create-react-app

I am trying to create a new React app with `create-react-app`. However, when I ran `npx create-react-app my-app` I got an error:

> npx: installed 67 in 8.408s You are running Node 12.22.0.

No worries, I went to the node.js site and downloaded and installed the latest version (18.1.0) and tried again, but got the same error.

Running `node -v` says I'm still using `12.22.-0`.

So I tried `npm install -g node --force`. Install went fine, but again running `node -v` still says I'm using 12.22.0 and `create-react-app` wont work.

I am on Mac OS.

What can I do?

Comment: Which OS is this? What does `which node` say? (Also, there's no good reason to run `npm install -g node` at all.)

Comment: Sorry - on Mac OS

Comment: Again, what does `which node` say? If you've installed Node.js via Homebrew earlier, then it may have precedence.

Comment: Sorry it says versions/node/v12.22.0/bin/node

Comment: Are you maybe using `nvm` or `asdf` or some other node version manager..?

Comment: I'm using NVM version manager

Comment: Well then you should use `nvm` to update Node.js, not `npm` or the node.js site?

Answer (score 0):

Node isn't installed via `npm`.

You need to either install Node via the official Mac OS installer, or via Brew (Recommended if you need more than one version)

https://nodejs.org/en/download/ - Download the Mac OS installer that suits your OS Version.

Comment: Yes, I have tried this already

Comment: And that didn't update Node in your OS? You need admin rights for it to work, that's the only obstacle you might face, unless you run out of disk space.